# Random UserID in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP project in which i want to create and assign random User IDs to my customers when they sign-up in to our company's second website. It must be random generated user Ids that must not duplicate in our MySQL Database. User IDs should be like `XYZ654986`, `HPR654986`, `WRU934765`, `SYW365824`.

How can I create , check and insert user IDs like these ?

Comment: What have you tried and what is your issue? SO is not a code writing service

Comment: What i tried is,  SELECT random
FROM (
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random 
  UNION
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random
) AS numbers_mst_plus_1
WHERE `random` NOT IN (SELECT my_number FROM numbers_mst)
LIMIT 1. ..

Comment: How is that ever going to give you the expected output of XYZ followed by numbers? What does your table consist of, where are the prefixed letters coming from? What does your PHP code look like with your SQL and what is the error?

Comment: It's been such a long time I'm playing with CISCO'S IDS , IPS and other firewall and security devices. It's pure Network security related things.. My world is full of Security and Data center related things. Now my hobby is learning php and sql and other languages.. If I know how to randomise XYZ part i wouldn't have come to Stack overflow to disturb people like Jaquarh 

Comment: Like I deviated to, SO is not a code writing service. Show us what you’ve done, what your issue is, your expected input and output - then we can help. So far, you’ve told us you want 3 letters and numbers without telling us where the 3 letters come from or what you’ve done

Comment: Looks no effort applied for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while random IDs for public services (like YouTube Video IDs) in the URL are useful, internally you shouldn't use random IDs. An ID which is used only backend could be made with AutoIncrement.

Nevertheless, you could have specific reasons to use a random ID.
First, you need to create a random code.
This creates a random code with the length 10 (you can change the length by changing `$i<10`):

```
$char = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
$chars = explode ( ",", $char );
$code = "";
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0, (count($chars)-1));
    $code .= $chars[$random];
}
```

Then, you need to check whether the code is already used or not.
If you have the codes in your MySQL database, you can use this:

```
$EveryID = array();
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ID FROM MyDatabase");
$statement->execute();   
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    array_push($EveryID, $row["ID"]);
}

$IDexists = false;
for ($i=0; $iy<count($EveryID), $i++) {
    if ($EveryID[$i] == $code) {
        $IDexists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And if `$IDexists` is true, you need to do the same (generate new code, etc.). I would do this with a while loop.
If `$IDexists` is false, you have a new unused code in `$code`. Then, you need to insert this code with other user information (e.g. name).
Here the full code:

```
$IDexists = true;

while ($IDexists == true) {

    $char = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
    $chars = explode ( ",", $char );
    $code = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $random = rand(0, (count($chars)-1));
        $code .= $chars[$random];
    }

    $EveryID = array();
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ID FROM MyDatabase");
    $statement->execute();   
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        array_push($EveryID, $row["ID"]);
    }

    $IDexists = false;
    for ($i=0; $iy<count($EveryID), $i++) {
        if ($EveryID[$i] == $code) {
            $IDexists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

}


$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO MyDatabase (ID, name, something) VALUES (:ID, :name, :sth)");
$statement->execute(array("ID" => $code, "Name" => $name, "sth" => $Something));
```

Requirements for this method are that you've made a PDO connection with your database at the beginning of your .php file. If you haven't made that, just google "php MySQL PDO" and look at a tutorial.

At last, I just want to say: If you use the IDs internally (that means the IDs aren't in the URL to the user's site), I'd recommend to make an Auto-Increment ID (that means, the first user has the ID 1, the second 2, etc.). You can set the ID in PhpMyAdmin as primary and check auto-Incrediment to do this (there are tutorials for this, too). That's way easier and for most use-cases more practical (but only if the IDs aren't in the URL on any place on your site).

Edit: Instead of

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    array_push($EveryID, $row["ID"]);
}
```

you can use

```
$EveryID = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Have you taken into consideration any performance before answering this? If the database has thousands of records, loooping through each record, randomising strings consistently is going to take a considerable amount of time, you never break out of the loop either when one does not exist. Don’t answer off topic questions, you motivate the OP to post future off topic questions again to do his work for him.

Comment: This world really needs people like Korne . Thank you so much for your reply.. for me this code is very important.. because i can learn lot of things by referring your code.. 

Comment: I can use 'die' after couple of checking.. so it won't loop forever

Comment: @Jaquarh You're right, I forgot to add a break statement (I've added it now).
The other thing doesn't make sense. This just randomises one code and checked whether it has been used already. It's simplified but not a bad solution, especially for the beginning of a project.
And why shouldn't I answer his question? Unlike you, I'm not just complaining, I'm at least being helpful.

Comment: @Jaquarh And why are you down voting me? Instead of you, I've made a correct, functional working solution which helps the author.

Comment: @Korne127 see how to [create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking a question on SO. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Jaquarh I haven't asked the question and you're right that it hasn't been asked good. But first, Shebeer is new to SO, and you shouldn't be harsh to a new contributor on his first question and second, I've made a good answer to the question which applies to everything, provided into your link.

Comment: Why create a whole new array? `$EveryID = $statement->fetchAll()`

Comment: @Shebeer If you have other issues in PHP, you should separate your problem into seperate parts and google to get solutions. For example, you could have been searching for "Generate PHP code", "MySQL PHP Tutorial", etc. StackOverflow is more for specific issues and not a general problem where you just need a code. I don't think, it's really serious (as Jarquarh) but it's something you could learn for the future :)

Comment: Ok i accepted SO is not a code writing service. I really don't know much about SO But why can't SO to help people who are very young at programming languages. Now i feel like code writing or learning is a criminal offence. Because you know the answer but you hate to help me on this matter. Because you don't want me to do this.. As I said I'm new to php and sql ..

Comment: @Shebeer Yeah, I know. That's the reason I've coded for you. But just search for tutorials at the beginning.
Here's a php beginner tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/php/
Sadly, I can't give you a good PDO tutorial as the one I've used is written in German. But there are plenty of other good tutorials.

Comment: @Shebeer if you have questions about a specific PHP function, like explode(), you can search on php.net. There are the functions explained.

Comment: I'm learning php and MySQL by referring Google. Google is my big teacher. I posted a question in SO because i want to know how SO is working.. How fast people answer my questions.. etc.. I got my first answer within minutes.. I'm very much excited about that.

Comment: @Jaquarh Can you say to me, what is so bad about my post? I think, this is rather an abuse to the voting system than an actual vote.